# Writing large Byte Arrays out on the fly (so memory doesn't become an issue)

Tags: java, io

I am reading some large files in as byte arrays and adding them to an arraylist. Bad... I end up with 100mb files IN MEMORY. I need them to be processed and output line by line (or every x number of lines). How do I do this? BufferedWriter doesn't take ByteArrays.

Comment: line by line? So are those text files? Then you should not read them as byte[], use a Reader instead (and read them line by line).

Comment: They are bytes from a database. Unfortunately I cannot cast them to strings in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine it all depends on how you are processing them. I you can process a single file at a time, do so. If the individual files are too large, read a 100K at a time, and parse for line breaks yourself. Process everything up to the last line break in the file, move the remainder to the beginning of the array and read more data. These are simple techniques, but without knowing more about how you are processing, that's about all I could suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a memory mapped file.  This way you have have MBs or GBs "in-memory" without using much heap at all. (a few KB).

If the data is from an external source you can still place them into direct memory or memory mapped files.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with data "on the fly" like this is called *streaming*. Data arrives from one stream, is processed, and saved to another stream, and you don't need to fit everything in memory.

If it's directly from database, `ResultSet` does not fetch all result rows at once. You can safely iterate over it in a loop and process rows "on the fly".

If it's a file, you can read it with a stream (e.g. `FileInputStream`) and prefetch smaller chunks. If it's a text file, use a `Reader` for all the automatic buffering and splitting on line breaks.

Wherever you get this data from, you can process it "on the fly" and write to output. Again, don't write to a byte array, but to stream - such as `FileOutputStream`, or a `Writer`.

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using BufferedReader

if you are using Java 7, try  nio2
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Comment: oops, didn't see its from database

Answer (score 0):

If they are binary files, then it does not make sense to talk about reading them line by line. Anyhow, if you want to process large files sequentially without having them in memory as a whole, you are interested in streaming those files. Have a look at the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` types. And avoid all types with 'ByteArray' in their name.